# Find rootscope parameters at controller on load

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-rootscope

I have defined rootscope parameters in `.run` method as follows. `

```
app.run(function($rootScope,$http) {
  $http.get('user/getBaseinfo').then(function success(response) {
    $rootScope.userRole = response.data.userRole;
    $rootScope.userRoleId = response.data.userRoleId;
 });
})`
```

as am injecting some parameters in rootscope. so when i print any variable in controller it gives undefined at first but if i am doing it on next call it gives the values. I did not understand the behavior. Can anybody help. 
my controller

```
app.controller('staffAttendanceController',['$scope','$http', '$rootScope',  function($scope, $http, $rootScope) {
 $scope.attendance_staff = {}; 

 console.log(userRole); //Undefined

 //Load data at first
 $http.get(API_URL + 'staffattend/listAll').then(function success(response) {
    $scope.attendance_staff = response.data.data;
    console.log(userRole); //Admin
 });
}]);
```

I want variable to be appear at very first line of controller which are declared in rootScope.

Comment: you need to access using $rootScope... console.log($rootScope.userRole);

Comment: it doesn't matter

Comment: Issue might be with async request.. instead of sending request at app.run create a service which returns promise and use in controller.. If you want value needs to be available on app ready.. create it as provider which can be used in app.config function.

Comment: okk Thank you @BEJGAMSHIVAPRASAD